# Prevent Jenkins from Building dependent modules

Tags: maven, jenkins, continuous-integration

I have a maven project, with 5 sub modules. Each module has a dependency on one of the 5 modules, however i do not want changes in one module to trigger builds of any of the modules. Can anyone point me in the right direction as to how to configure this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: i can't grasp how your proect is formed, you have a 'pom' maven project with 5 modules, and those have dependencies in between. That's ok, a maven build in any of them but the 'pom' one, shouldn't trigger any dependency build.

Comment: the pom one is the parent, this is not being built. But a change in any of the modules - now they are set up as independent build jobs - does trigger a build in all the other modules, which is what i am trying to stop

Comment: a parent project and a 'pom' packaging project serves different purposes, post the pom and build commands

Answer (score 0):

Just create 5 different Jenkins jobs. One for each module. Since every module has it's own pom.xml, this should be no problem. The problem with that is, if two modules change, you have to build them in the right order. This has to be done manually as far as I know.

Comment: I have done this - everything is in mercurial and Jenkins is polling the SCM repository for the project, i have created 5 separate jobs but all from the same repository, and when a build is triggered due to an SCM change all 5 modules are being built. this is causing problems with versioning and deployment to maven repositories. I do not really want to break up the project and take away the parent pom, but i do want to build each module separately so that i do not have to keep increasing version numbers on projects

Comment: I just found the option `Incremental build - only build changed modules` in the `Build`->`Advanced` section of the job configuration. Have you tried that one? Maybe you can have just one job again with that option.

Comment: Then I'm out of ideas too. Sorry!

Comment: thanks for the suggestions Andre, i guess i have to break the project up into separate stand alone projects, which is frustrating